# Negative Numbers over TCP socket C

Tags: c, sockets, tcp

Whenever I try to send a negative number over a TCP socket, when I print what was received,it reads "4.29497e+09". All I'm doing is this:

```
int i = -8;
int temp = htonl(i);
write(sock,&temp,4);
```

On the Server:

```
int temp;
read(sock, &temp,4);
int read = ntohl(temp);
cout << read << endl;
```

If anyone could help, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: You are forgetting to convert from network to host order after you `read()`

Comment: You're making a few assumptions about the size of an int.

Comment: You forgot to check the return value from `read`! What if it's 3? Also, don't give the variable the same name as a function, that's just asking for trouble. And you should use the correct type (`uint32_t`) with `htonl`/`ntohl`.

Comment: @tpg2114: this is not mandatory, as long as both endpoints use the same architecture

Comment: @valdo Maybe if was `sizeof(int)` being used here - but it's not, it's the arbitrary number 4.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin Currently the server and client are using the same architecture, so as valdo said, it can be a fixed number.

Comment: Even assuming that a particular compiler for your architecture is always going to have sizeof(int) == 4 is a mistake. Plus if you forget about it when you're porting your application later, there won't be an error - you'll just get a bad value and corrupt the memory beyond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When transferring data over a socket, you don't need to convert it to network endianess.
This function is used to translate addresses, not actual data. These functions work with unsigned integers, so they don't match your argument (signed integer)

**You need to omit them.**

If the second machine uses different endianess, which is kind of rare (both 8086 and ARM architectures work with little endian), you need to swap the bytes when reading ints and shorts.
This is usually done on the receiving socket.

Comment: I had that in the code, just re-typed everything. Edit reflects that.

Comment: Try emitting the ntohl and htonl

Answer (score 4):

The `htonl`/`ntohl` functions are specifically for unsigned 32-bit integers.

> The `htonl()` function converts the **unsigned** integer `hostlong` from host byte order to network byte order.